# Google Analytics time required for data to be displayed on dashboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, google-analytics

I am working on an iOS app in Swift 3, I have integrated SDK for Google Analytics in the app and with the help of below code, I am trying to send the data to Analytics.

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().tracker(withTrackingId: "Some_Id")
tracker?.set("Studio", value: "Android")
let build = (GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as NSDictionary) as! [AnyHashable: Any]
tracker?.send(build)
GAI.sharedInstance().trackUncaughtExceptions = true
```

But I am unable to see any data on the dashboard page of Google Analytics. Its been more than 12 hours now, but no data. 
Can anybody suggest how long can it take to reflect the data on the dashboard?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Usually it takes around 24 hours. To get real time data, on the dashboard page of Google Analytics, select Real Time.

Comment: Not getting real time data.